# usb_cam on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera-drivers, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use usb_cam on ubuntu 11.10 and ROS electric.
when I use rosmake usb_cam --rosdep-install, it says:
Failed to find rosdep libswscale for package usb_cam on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric

while I check libswscale, libswscale-dev and libswscale2 were installed in my system.
any ideas to solve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28368/usb_cam-on-ubuntu-11.10/) by [Parisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/1846/parisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use gscam pkg instead of usb_cam

---

Originally posted by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) with karma: 41 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0